# SpeechSynthesizer audio to text as its spoken

Tags: wpf, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis

I Am currently working on a project where I want to have the SpeechSynthesizer speak a text. I also want a textblock to display the words as they are spoken. This is so you can read along if you don't understand the Speech Synthesizer.

So basically the problem is that i cant find a efficient way to append every letter to a text within a textbox right when its spoken by the Speech Synthesizer. So it looks like the Speech Synthesizer is typing along with what he is saying.

**Example**

If I would do this:

```
SpeechSynthesizer x = new SpeechSynthesizer();
x.SpeakAsync("Hello there");
```

I want the textbox text to write along as the words are spoken by the x (SpeechSynthesizer ). Something like this:
http://youtu.be/hx6JL7PsLrg?t=1m56s

Comment: Since I can't add an answer here - you want to use the [`SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric mentioned, you have to use the *SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakProgress* event:

For Example:

```
var ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
ss.SpeakProgress += (sender, args) => txtBox.Text += args.Text;
ss.Speak("Hello this is " + true);
```

Comment: Alright I will try this when asap. But I can imagine that this would display word after word. I want it more like a teleprompter. So it looks like its type along or is that really hard to do?

Comment: I don't know how teleprompters shows the script. Do you mean letter by letter?

Comment: I found a clip that show the perfect way for me. Is this hard to do?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKHLescbo8o&feature=c4-overview&list=UUxqlwcSqWwC9-qB0v6plqxw

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hacky (and isn't guaranteed to do letter-by-letter), but you could use the [`PhonemeReached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.phonemereached%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event as a hint to display the next letter (and stop at word breaks) and then use the [`SpeakProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event to generate the remaining letters in the word.  If you're using SSML, you'll need to skip over markup, of course.